# Calculating Volume using Shell Method

Tags: calculus, geometry

[image]

Hey everyone,

I'm trying to do this problem and I'm just a little confused. when it says to the right of x=0.5 does that mean I should subtract the integral by 0.5 and I'm confused on whether I should solve this equation in terms of x or y. Can someone help me?

Comment: Let $x^2=8-x^2$ at $x=\chi$. Then, if $8-x^2>x^2$ in the interval $[0.5,\chi]$, then the integral for the volume is $2\pi\int x(8-x^2-x^2)dx$, else the integral is $2\pi\int x(x^2-(8-x^2))dx$.

Comment: @SanathDevalapurkar Feel free to not answer, but are you really 13? Some kind of prodigy?

Comment: @dfg I am 13, but I don't consider myself to be a prodigy.

Comment: @SanathDevalapurkar I don't know many 13 year olds who write papers on quantum mechanics and help university students with their homework. How else would you define prodigy? :)

Comment: @dfg Thank you. I am doing these things out of a deep and aesthetic interest in mathematics, and I am proud to have joined this esteemed mathematics community. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Draw a picture. The curves meet at $x=2$ (and $x=-2$, but that's irrelevant). Draw the line $x=0.5$. Make sure you see clearly the region we are rotating.

Now draw a thin vertical strip "at" $x$, where $0.5\lt x\lt 2$, and  of width "$dx$." The strip is at distance $x$ from the $y$-axis, so the radius of your cylindrical shell is $x$. The height of the shell is $(8-x^2)-x^2=8-2x^2$. The volume of the shell is approximately $2\pi(x)(8-2x^2)\,dx$. "Add up" (integrate) from $x=0.5$ to $x=2$. We get
$$\int_{0.5}^2  2\pi x(8-2x^2)\,dx.$$